# Implicit parameter in super class scope

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, superclass

In my current project, we've got a trait with a method like:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def foo(bar: Request => IntermediateResult): Result = {
    val request: Request = ???
    bar(request).toResult(request)
  }
}
```

In some cases though, we would need to return an instance of `Result` directly. So I thought I could simply change the signature of the `foo` method to take a function parameter of type `Request => Result` and supply an implicit conversion from a `Request => IntermediateResult` function to `Request => Result`:

```
implicit def intermediateResult2Result(handle: Request => IntermediateResult)(implicit request: Request) =
  handle.andThen(_.toResult(request))
```

However, this requires that the `request` instance is implicitly available. So my idea was to rewrite `foo` to:

```
def foo(bar: Request => Result): Result = {
  implicit val request: Request = ???
  bar(request)
}
```

However, now the call to `foo` should now include the an `implicit request` parameter rather than just a plain `request`. Is there any way to get around this restriction?

Comment: Don't use implicit conversions and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it to be so complicated. Just add another flavor of `foo`

```
def foo(bar: Request => IntermediateResult) = bar(request).toResult
def fooBar(bar: Request => Result) = bar(request)
```

Comment: Adding another method would indeed solve the problem, it just isn't quite that nice :( I'll discuss it with the rest of my team here.

Comment: I think, this is actually waaay nicer, then implicit conversions happening magically. Imagine yourself reading a piece of code, you have not seen before, doing something like `"foo".multiplyBy(15).sendToServer() andThen crash() unless everythingIsPeachy` ...

Answer (score 0):

If you formulate your implicit conversion a bit differently, you'll no longer need the implicit parameter:

```
implicit def intermediateResult2Result(handle: Request => IntermediateResult): Request => Result =
  {request: Request => handle(request).toResult(request)}
```